# Spring AOP : Parameter passed as null for an interface with @Around aspect

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem where I am using @Around in two interfaces that are configured as Spring beans. One of those interface is a parameter to another interface and is always getting passed as null value. Following is the code snippet

```
      public interface Interface1 {
          public void method1();
      }

      public interface Interface2 {
          public void method2(Interface1 param1);
      }

      @Around("execution(* Interface1.method1(..))")
      private void interceptor1(ProceedingJoinPoint pJoinPoint) throws Throwable{
        //do something
      }

       @Around("execution(* Interface2.method2(..))")
      private void interceptor2(ProceedingJoinPoint pJoinPoint) throws Throwable{
        //do something
      }
```

In the calling code to Interface2 I always get the parameter param1 to method2 as null.
If I remove the @Around("execution(* Interface1.method1(..))") above it works fine. The reason for adding the @Around for both of them is to catch the Exceptions for logging and audit purpose and to stop the rest of the exceptions to be propagated.

Can you please help me around this problem?

Comment: Post your aspect implementation as well. One thing I already notice that your aspect is wrong, an around aspect should always return Object not void and in the implementation always return the result of the call to `proceed()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Aspects are flawed. An around aspect should **always** have a return type of `Object` not `void`. Returning void basically destroys the proper passing of return values from the callstack, remember that the around aspect puts code **around** your method execution!

So change your aspect to return object and always return the result of the call to `proceed()`

```
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
  // Your stuff to do before the method call here
  Object returnValue = pjp.proceed();
  // Your stuff to do after the method call here
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: His aspects are there (well not code wise) but the method signatures are.